# Pandas Error: sequence item 0: expected str instance, NoneType found

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe as below:

```
Car_Modal    Color     Number_Passenger
Proton       Black     5
Proton       Black     7
Perudua      White     5
Perudua      White     7
Perudua      Red       7
Honda                  5
```

Due to the Honda row have Null value at Color column, is show me error when I used below code:

`df["Join"]=df.groupby("Car_Modal")["Color"].transform(lambda x :'<br>'.join(x.unique()))`

Expected Output:

```
Car_Modal    Color     Number_Passenger     Join
Proton       Black     5                    Black
Proton       Black     7                    Black
Perudua      White     5                    White<br>Red
Perudua      White     7                    White<br>Red
Perudua      Red       7                    White<br>Red
Honda                  5
```

Anyone can share me ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Would you mind adding an expected output? I feel like I have an idea, having an expected output will make sure I match what you want the output of your code to be

Comment: You might need to use fillna() to impute missing values first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try filtering data that are not null

```py
df["Join"]=df[~df["Color"].isnull()].groupby("Car_Modal")["Color"] \
    .transform(lambda x :'<br>'.join(x.unique()))
```

Answer (score 2):

you can build a filter to filter based on whether there is a null value in a specific column using [pandas.Series.notnull](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notnull.html) :

```
filter_Color_null=df['Color'].notnull()
df["Join"]=df[filter_Color_null].groupby("Car_Modal")["Color"].transform(lambda x :'<br>'.join(x.unique()))
```

You also can filter by any column of the DataFrame using [DataFrame.notnull](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notnull.html):

```
filter_null=df.notnull().all(axis=1)
df["Join"]=df[filter_null].groupby("Car_Modal")["Color"].transform(lambda x :'<br>'.join(x.unique()))
```